# No update to the view is executed by calling the sort function

Tags: javascript, typescript, reactjs

I have created this React component in Typescript

```
import * as React from "react";

import { IExcelProps } from "../interfaces/ExcelProps";
import { IExcelState } from "../interfaces/ExcelState";

class Excel extends React.Component<IExcelProps, IExcelState> {

  name = "Excel";

  static propTypes: React.ValidationMap<any> = {
    header: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(
      React.PropTypes.string
    ).isRequired,
    initialData: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(
      React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.string)
    ).isRequired
  }

  // this correspond to getInitialState
  initialState : IExcelState = {
    data: this.props.initialData
  };

  constructor(excelProps: IExcelProps) {
    super(excelProps);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState(new ExcelState(this.initialState.data));
  }

  // This cause the following warning:
  // =================================
  // Warning: getInitialState was defined on Excel, a plain JavaScript class
  // This is only supported for classes created using React.createClass.
  // Did you mean to define a state property instead?
  // =================================
  // getInitialState() {
  //   return {
  //     data: this.props.initialData
  //   };
  // }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="panel panel-default">
        <div className="panel-heading">Airports Codes</div>
        <table className="table">
          <thead onClick={this._sort}>
            <tr>
              {this._renderHeader(this.props.header)}
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this._renderTableBody(this.state.data)}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }

  private _renderHeader(header: string[]) : React.ReactElement<any>[] {
    return (
      header.map((value, idx) => {
        return <th key={idx}>{value}</th>
      })
    );
  }

  private _renderTableBody(body: string[][]) : React.ReactElement<any>[] {
    return (
      body.map((row, idx) => {
        return (
          <tr key={idx}>
          {
            row.map((value, idx) => {
              return <td key={idx}>{idx === 1 ? this._beautifyTypeColumn(value) : value}</td>
            })
          }
          </tr>
        );
      })
    );
  }

  private _sort(event) {
    // this get the cellIndex corresponding with the header column
    var column = event.target.cellIndex;
    // returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object.
    var dataTemp = this.state.data.slice();
    this.setState(new ExcelState(dataTemp.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      return b[column] - a[column];
    })));
  }

  private _beautifyTypeColumn(value: string) : string {
    return this._capitalizeEachWord(value.replace('_', ' '));
  }

  private _capitalizeEachWord(value: string) : string {
    return value.replace(/\w\S*/g, (txt) => {
        return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    });
  }
}

// XXX: move somewhere else
class ExcelState implements IExcelState {
  data : string[][];

  constructor(data: string[][]) {
    this.data = data;
  }
}

export default Excel;
```

what should do this component basically is to show the data that receive and when the user click on the header it should sort the element. unfortunately it doesn't work and I'm not able to figure out why. I call correctly `_sort` function but it doesn't work.

Comment: The problem is that wherever I put the onClick function it doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe I know the reason because this code doesn't work. I render the code in a jade template passing the above React component to the function renderToString in the backend but in the front there is anything. Should I have some react in the script? I suppose yes